# Profile Common in Visual Web Developer 2010 Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-profiles

I know that ProfileCommon is not available in a Web Application Project (WAP), but I am using the Website type instead. I put this into my web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <profile enabled="true">
    <properties>
      <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="LastName" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="Address" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="City" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="State" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="Zip" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="Email" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="Birthday" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="ProfilePicture" type="System.String"/>
      <add name="ProfilePictureThumb" type="System.String"/>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>
</system.web>
```

and when I try to add the

```
ProfileCommon profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;
```

statement into a .cs file I get the

```
The type or namespace name 'ProfileCommon' could not be found (are you missing a using directiv or assembly reference)
```

I am using the imports

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Profile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post will help you : [WebProfile Builder and WAP for VS2010](http://www.kps-fl.com/blog/?p=17)

`ProfileCommon` is dynamic class. you can create instant of that using below line of code.

```
var profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile;
```

[image]

If you need to set property values:

```
profile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName","testName");
```

Comment: I did that but I still cannot see the profile attributes that are defined in the web.config file. For instance, firstName = profile.FirstName throws the error System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase does not contain a definition for FirstName

Comment: @UnhandledException- I'm still confused about how this works exactly.